# How to build a C++ Dll wrapper that catches all exceptions?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, visual-c++

Like the title says, we’re looking for a way to catch all exceptions from a piece of C++ code, and wrap this in a dll. This way we can shield of the application that uses this dll, from any errors occurring in this dll.

However, this does not seem possible with C++ under Windows.

Example:

```
void function()
{  
    try  
    {    
        std::list<int>::iterator fd_it;
        fd_it++;  
    } catch(...) {}
}
```

The exception that occurs is not caught by the standard C++ try/catch block, nor by any SEH translator function set by `_set_se_translator()`. Instead, the DLL crashes, and the program that uses the DLL is aborted. We compiled with Visual C++ 2005, with the option /SHa. Does anyone know if it’s possible in C++/Win32 to catch these kind of problems and make a rocksolid DLL wrapper?

Comment: Same as [C++ catching all exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315948/c-catching-all-exceptions)

Answer (score 25):

The only way to make a rock solid DLL wrapper is to load the buggy DLL in another process, so that if it crashes it doesn't take your primary process down with it.

Catching all C++ exceptions seems reasonable, but catching all structured exceptions is another story. SEH might *seem* to get you most of the way there, because it allows you to catch access violations, divide-by-zero exceptions, etc.

But what if the buggy DLL happens to touch an uncommitted page from another thread's stack? The memory access will page fault, the exception handler will be invoked, and now that page is no longer a guard page. When that thread needs to grow the stack, it will get an access violation, and the process will crash. ([These](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2004/05/18/134471.aspx) [posts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563) describe this case in more detail.)

Another likely problem: the buggy DLL crashes while holding a synchronization object, but you use SEH to catch the exception. If your process attempts to acquire the same synchronization object, then it deadlocks instead of crashing. The shared synchronization object may be part of the C runtime or the OS: what if buggy DLL 1 loads buggy DLL 2, which crashes in its `DllMain()` while buggy DLL 1 is holding the loader lock? Will your process deadlock the next time it loads a DLL?

For more information on why this (and functions like `IsBadReadPtr()`, which have similar problems) is a misuse of SEH:

- Larry Osterman's WebLog: [Structured Exception Handling Considered Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2004/09/10/228068.aspx)
- Larry Osterman's WebLog: [Should I check the parameters to my function?](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2004/05/18/134471.aspx)
- Larry Osterman's WebLog: [Resilience is NOT necessarily a good thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2008/05/01/resilience-is-not-necessarily-a-good-thing.aspx)
- The Old New Thing: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563)

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, C++ has 2 different styles of exceptions: C++ and SEH exceptions.

SEH is a windows only form of exceptions (*somewhat* akin to signals in UNIX).  It's more of a system level exception.  They will be thrown for such operations as invalid pointer accesses, alignment issues, etc ...

If you want to catch every exception that can be thrown by a C++ app on windows you will need to catch both.  Fortunately there is a way to mix the use of C++ and SEH exceptions.  I wrote a detailed blog post about this recently, it should help you out.

http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/01/11/mixing-seh-and-c-exceptions.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The code below is taken from the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) IDE. It will trap any Windows generated exceptions:

**Step #1:** Define an Exception Filter Function

```
  DWORD ExceptionFilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pointers, DWORD dwException)
  {
    //-- we handle all exceptions
    DWORD dwResult = EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;

    switch (dwException)
    {
      case EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:
      case EXCEPTION_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT:
      case EXCEPTION_ARRAY_BOUNDS_EXCEEDED:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_INEXACT_RESULT:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_OVERFLOW:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK:
      case EXCEPTION_FLT_UNDERFLOW:
      case EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
      case EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW:
      case EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION:
      case EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE_EXCEPTION:
      case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
        dwResult = EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
        break;
    }

    return dwResult;
  }
```

**Step #2:** Wrap the code in a *__try* and *__except* as shown below:

```
  __try
  {
    // call your dll entry point here
  }
  __except(ExceptionFilter(GetExceptionInformation(), 
                           GetExceptionCode()))
  {
    //-- display the fatal error message
    MessageBox(0, "An unexpected error was caught here!", 
               "Unexpected Error", MB_OK);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Konrad Rudolph: Of course this code contains a "logic error", it's to illustrate a problem that could occur.  Like the man says he wants to be able to shield his dll from any possible errors. You don't think this is a legitimate question? Heard of vendor products. Some of us live in the real world and live with real problems.  It's just not possible to fix everyone else's problems

Comment: You may better write this as a comment on Konrad Rudolphs answer than making it an answer to the question itself. I had my problems finding his obvious answer any helpful also.

Answer (score 3):

Incrementing an iterator on a standard libary container will never throw a C++ exception. It may give you undefined behaviour.

Comment: It can throw a structured exception which is a Microsoft compiler thing. With those you can catch divides by zero, bad memory access, etc... The semantics are different than C++ exceptions.

Comment: Which is undefined behaviour from a Standard C+++ perspective

Comment: Sure, sure I wasn't disagreeing. Just pointing out in VC++ it actually will throw something that can be caught by catch(...). But this isn't standard C++ by any means.

Answer (score 3):

*This* code contains a logic error, if at all. Since a logic error constitues a bug, don't swallow the exception – **fix the error**!

Of course, this is specific to the particular code. Others have offered more general advice. However, I've found that a lot of people actually *do* prefer catching exceptions over fixing logic errors and this is simply unacceptable.

Comment: An exception does not mean error. It's just an exception. They happen, that is why they exist. Whether this is smart principle would go to far off topic. (Not a fan, opens a second program flow path). Errors can rise from exceptions that are not caught. If there is no other appropriate place to catch the exception, you can catch it at the highest level. That is completely acceptable, as long as the exception is caught.

Comment: @thewhiteambit I’m not talking in general, I’m talking about OP’s specific code.

Comment: I don't see specific code in the question here. Maybe it's a third party DLL he can't make catch the exception. Maybe the exception thrown is perfectly fine for the DLL. It's a valid question. Your answer is making general assumptions that are not valid and doesn't answer the question he asked.

Comment: @thewhiteambit Then it’s on OP to provide more information and/or relevant code. As I said *very explicitly* (both in my previous comment an in my answer), my advice applies to the specific code shown by OP, and is an addition to other, more general answers.

Comment: I think the OP intentionally had no specific code, but just an vague example, because he wanted to avoid answers like "you better fix that error than catch the exeptions". The question was specific about techniques catching all possible exceptions in a DLL wrapper, not about fixing any DLL. The unspecific DLL should be assumed broken and not fixable. Why would you even wrap a DLL then, and not at least catch the exeptions within that DLL. Particular code shows "catch(...)" is not capable of catching all exceptions, and he asked how to catch them. Not whether to avoid it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the windows API function SetUnhandledExceptionFilter?

I usually call it in the DllMain function and have it generate a minidump when the DLL crashes. However: (a) I don't know if it traps application exceptions as well as DLL exceptions, and (b) I don't know if you can have the handler return in such a way that program execution can continue. The docs say yes, but I've never done it.

Answer (score 1):

What are you going to do after you catch the exception (especially for SEH exceptions)?

In reality you can make no assumptions about the state of the process, realistically the only option you have is to (optionally) dump core and exit.

Any attempt and proceeding is absolutely going to cause you problems in the long run.