# Can segmentation faults in C++ be handled in the same way as NullPointerExceptions would be handled in Java?

Tags: java, c++, segmentation-fault

I realize that the state of a computation is effectively corrupted after a segmentation fault (C++) and a NullPointerExeception (Java) but this does not mean the whole application should shut down. 
In a well designed cohesive system, other computations should be able to complete successfully providing the desired result.

In Java we would simple catch the NullPointerException and skip over the computation where possible.
Can the same effect be achieved in C++. Ie for a computation can we define specific code which executes after a segmentation fault, which resulted from a specific computation, in much the same way as try catch blocks are used in Java?

A simple example would be in an event loop, if one of the events causes a seg fault, skip to processing the next event.

A another example is in Algo trading you would pause the execution of an order and allow a trader to manually take over, with out crashing the entire system and ruining all other orders.

So i'm looking for C++ code which achieves handling seg faults in the same way as NullPointerException's in the below.

```
try {
   computation();
} catch (NullPointerException e){
   // specific code for handling the problem in the above execution of computation();
}
```

Comment: I question this assertion:  "after a segmentation fault [...] this does not mean the whole application should shut down. "

Comment: _In a well designed cohesive system_ application **must terminate**. Also in Java. **Are you SURE about application's state** after such exception? If it was a known scenario then you wouldn't get such exception. What about intermediate results? Are they valid? Handling the problem is often log and save something (**if you're sure data isn't corrupted**). In C++ scenario is even worse because problem is _detected_ in one point but originated somewhere else (even long time before).

Comment: There is a reason that NPE is not a checked exception in Java.  You generally don't want to catch it, but would rather let the application fail since this indicates a fundamental flaw in your program which needs fixing (i.e. add null checking).

Comment: You could _prevent_ a segfault, in some cases, through use of `std::shared_ptr` + `std::weak_ptr`, calling `weak_ptr.lock` allows you to check for invalid (or Null- if you will) pointers

Comment: There may be some platform-specific ways (SEH on Windows, for instance). However, as far as the language is concerned, if you get a segfault you are in UB territory.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350489/how-to-catch-segmentation-fault-in-linux

Comment: Are you trying to use null pointer exceptions as a branching mechanism in C++?  Especially in the algo trading space, this is a terrible architectural choice, if for no other reason than the expense involved in handling exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Generally the answer is no. But there are some system-specific ways to handle such exceptional situations.

Let me first explain the "no" part. C++ does not throw exceptions in case of dereferencing null pointer, or other segmentation fault errors. Those errors are treated in the same way as e.g. out-of-bounds array access - nothing is checked and the code is just executed. The programmer is responsible for ensuring that such errors are not encountered - e.g. the pointer can be explicitly checked if it is null before using.

In most of the systems the underlying hardware and OS mechanism disallows access and e.g. stops the program with segmentation fault error when null pointer is dereferenced. But there are systems where dereferencing null pointer will not cause segmentation fault. No matter how such cases are handled, C++ does not (and most probably never will) contain mechanisms to check for them and throw exceptions.

Still there are system-dependent ways of handling such situations such as signals in *nix systems, SEH in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> I realize that the state of a computation is effectively corrupted after a segmentation fault

A segmentation fault says you have a bug which it is likely your application cannot recover from.  But I would argue this does not corrupt the memory as this cannot alter the memory.  It may be an indication your memory was corrupted earlier.

> Can the same effect be achieved in C++. Ie for a computation can we define specific code which executes after a segmentation fault, which resulted from a specific computation, in much the same way as try catch blocks are used in Java?

In theory, this might be possible.  C++ now supports exceptions.  IMHO C++ can do anything Java does, the question is would they ever want to.  In practice, I don't image this will ever be implemented as standard.

> In a well designed cohesive system application must terminate

While I agree with this, in Java you have some flexibility as to your definition of an application.  For example, a Java process can have multiple applications running in it which can be loaded, unloaded and upgraded at runtime.  A critical error could cause one of the applications become unusable, but this doesn't mean the whole process has to die.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done with exception catching mechanisms in C++, but this can be achieved on `POSIX`-compliant systems with `sigaction`, which allows you to call a function when a certain signal is received

[Example of signal handling](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigaction-Function-Example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. In my experience I sometimes find that the failed operation causes future operations to be rather useless (since they are operating on data that should have been updated by the failed operation, but wasn't), or that many operations fail for the same reason. But sometimes it does allow mostly-correct execution of the program.

You many need to do some compiler/OS-specific things in order to be able to catch the segmentation fault, but I think that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ the only good solution is to fix the code, if you can't, the signal handling explained in other answers is risky but maybe it works.

My preferred solution if I had to manage a program that segfaults would be to create a separated process for the buggy code. That way the process can crash freely and be relaunched or cleaned from a safe process.