# Does C get try&catch to guarantee no core dump will crash?

Tags: c, linux

Normally when a foo() have memory problem the whole program will simply core dump, crash. But does C have any protection ways to guarantee a program will not crash, just goto a state or simply return, when core dump happens inside foo()?

Comment: If there's a memory problem, you **want** it to crash.  Otherwise, your program will likely exhibit strange behavior you can't explain.

Comment: To enlarge on the @dbush comment, unfortunately there is no guarantee that a "memory problem" will actually crash a C program - it can just give wrong results.  All you can say is that a crash *might eventually* occur.  Results can also be non-deterministic, depending on the cause, particularly in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: By the way, there is no `try` and `catch` in standard C.  Windows C supports `__try` and `__except`, but that is non-standard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. I mean, is there anyway when a function has memory problem, do not let it core dump but stop and show some message. I google out some function inside setjmp.h may help. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I dont think so, function know that it has core dump only when it happens. There is no way how to predict it (for the function).

Comment: The only way to get round a crash is to avoid situations causing it.

Comment: @alk This is useless as wear more cloth to avoid sick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not say for try and catch statement in c but yes you can write signal handler to catch segfault. 
Here is a link.
[How to catch segmentation fault in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350489/how-to-catch-segmentation-fault-in-linux)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350489/how-to-catch-segmentation-fault-in-linux/2436368#2436368

Comment: Catching a `SIGSEGV` mostly never helps. If the stack had been smashed, or memory management info got deleted, messed-up, or WTF got lost there is no chance to recover from this.