# How can I catch runtime error in C++

Tags: c++

By referring to [C++ catching all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315948/c-catching-all-exceptions)

```
try {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0/i; /* Division by  0 */
    int *k = 0;
    std::cout << *k << std::endl;  /* De-reference invalid memory location. */
}
catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Opps!" << std::endl;
}
```

The above run-time error are unable to be detected. Or, am I having wrong expectation on C++ exception handling feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you dereference a pointer that doesn't point to an object, you don't get an exception, you get undefined behavior.  Anything can happen.

Usually, if you dereference a null pointer, as you do in your example, the program will crash.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I am mixing Java's Exception system with C++'s Exception.

Answer (score 3):

/EHa is the magic compiler switch to make Visual Studio treat SEH exceptions as C++ exceptions. Then you can "catch" access violation and divide by zero exceptions.

This is generally not advised.

Comment: COOL! I never know about /EHa options.

Comment: nice stuff, I didn't know about this either

Answer (score 2):

When you run this program (at least on my system when *I* run it), you aren't throwing C++ exceptions; you're actually segfaulting the standard C library.  A segmentation fault in a library is *not* a C++ exception, so the C++ runtime has nothing to catch.

Contrasting this program with, say, an equivalent program in C# or Java, the difference is that their respective runtimes will treat these errors runtime exceptions and will not segmentation fault any external libraries.

Comment: Actually when they segfault an external lib (which is really rare) the program terminates...

Answer (score 1):

These are not C++ exceptions. These are OS exceptions. If you are using Windows, you can enable asynchronous exception model (/EHa flag) and catch Win32 exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime environment C++ gives you is very thin. In most cases it will do what you program it to do and won't do what you don't program it to do. You can write a wrapper for your pointers which will do the check when you dereference a null pointer. In fact, `boost::shared_ptr<>` does assert for not equalling null when you dereference it, so you get a similar performance to that of native pointers while giving the extra information you're after while debugging.