# What can I do with an std::exception_ptr other than rethrowing it

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have an object of type `std::exception_ptr`, and I want to call `what()` on it, but it seems there is no way to do this (As explaned in this answer: [How do I make a call to what() on std::exception_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232814/how-do-i-make-a-call-to-what-on-stdexception-ptr)).

After searching over internet, it seems that I can not do anything with it other than re-throwing it and catching it in a `std::exception&` to be able to do this.

It is a bit strange for me, but I want to check: What can do with a `std::exception_ptr` other then re-throwing it to get the detail of expectation?

Is there any change in C++14 or other versions of C++

Comment: as far as I can tell it is only useful if you want to defer the exception handling until you do something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a call to what() on std::exception\_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232814/how-do-i-make-a-call-to-what-on-stdexception-ptr)

Comment: How do you know the exception currently held by the `exception_ptr` actually inherited from `std::exception`?

Comment: @Barry You don't, other than rethrowing the exception and trying to catch it as `std::exception&`

Comment: @lcs I know - the question was for OP.

Comment: There is a proposal to add type introspection for std::exception_ptr: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0933r0.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. The standard only guarantees the following for `std::exception_ptr`:

> 18.8.5 Exception propagation
>
> 1 The type exception_ptr can be used to refer to an exception object.
>
> 2 exception_ptr shall satisfy the requirements of NullablePointer (17.6.3.3).
>
> 3 Two non-null values of type exception_ptr are equivalent and compare equal if and only if they refer
>   to the same exception.
>
> 4 The default constructor of exception_ptr produces the null value of the type.
>
> 5 exception_ptr shall not be implicitly convertible to any arithmetic, enumeration, or pointer type.
>
> 7 For purposes of determining the presence of a data race, operations on exception_ptr objects shall
>   access and modify only the exception_ptr objects themselves and not the exceptions they refer to.

Additionally, noted [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception_ptr/),

> Performing any other operation on the object (such as dereferencing it), if at all supported by the library implementation, causes *undefined behavior*.