# why ... (three points) in catch block is exist?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, catch-block

In the try catch statement we can do:

```
try{}
catch(...){}
```

As far as I know, `...` means any exception.

**My question is**: Why the C++ standard chose this way `(...)` instead of just `()`? while, for example, in functions if you do not need parameters you just put `()`:

```
void foo();
```

Is it related to variadic templates in any way?

Comment: In C++, unlike in C, `()` means `(void)` it doesn't mean any argument but rather a parameter list with no argument.

Comment: [Read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: it is not duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315948/c-catching-all-exceptions. please at least read the question

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks I will do that

Comment: It's just an elegant way to say "anything". Maybe it could be better to use the `default` key-word in a similar way of switches...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`catch()` would imply strongly that nothing was passed to that particular catch block.

But that is not true,

```
catch(...){
    throw;
}
```

actually re-throws the exception caught by `...`

Comment: nice point.. so internally the exception is cached by a hidden variable

Answer (score 8):

It has nothing to do with variadic templates, because those came in C++11 whereas `catch (...)` existed from nearly the beginning (about two decades earlier).

As for why they chose `(...)` instead of `()`, you could ask Bjarne Stroustrup, but it hardly seems important.  This feature isn't used all that often anyway.  In C++, `(...)` usually means something like "Any number of things of any types" whereas `()` usually means "Nothing."  Depending on your perspective, either one of these might be more preferred for "catch all exceptions."

Comment: It's really often used if you want something robust.