# Does a throw in catch(...) throw by value or by reference

Tags: c++

My boss answered this question [why ... (three points) in catch block is exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737602/why-three-points-in-catch-block-is-exist/36738071#36738071) quite elegantly.

But it's made me think of something (and hopefully makes up for my previous bad question), does

```
catch(...){
    throw;
}
```

rethrow the caught exception by *value* (i.e. a deep copy is taken), or by *reference*?

Comment: _The re-thrown exception object is the original exception object, not a copy._  Taken from the Remarks in [try, throw and catch statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6dekhbbc.aspx). So based on that, I assume by reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [do the default catch throw statements in C++ pass by value or reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562053/do-the-default-catch-throw-statements-in-c-pass-by-value-or-reference)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard says:

> A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception. The exception is reactivated with the existing temporary; no new temporary exception object is created.

*-- ISO/IEC 14882:2011 Section 15.1 par. 8*

In other words, it simply continues the exception propagation with the original exception object. I suppose this is analogous to what you mean by "by reference".

Comment: The location has changed in later drafts §5.17/3, but the wording and intent remain; [see here for a link](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.throw#3). And this quote *"If a handler exits by rethrowing, control is passed to another handler for the same exception."* from [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/except#except.throw-4).