# How should I exit a C++ program cleanly after printing the CLI help message from a function?

Tags: c++, exception, exit, args, boost-program-options

I'm trying to figure out the best way to exit my program cleanly after printing the CLI help information in my program. Currently it looks like this.

```
int main(int argc, *char[] argv) {
    try {
    std::string settings_file = process_args(argc, argv);

    do_more_stuff();
    ...
    ...
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE)
    }
}

std::string process_args(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    boost::program_options::options_description desc("Program options");
    desc.add_options()("help,h", "Print usage message")(
      "settings,s", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(),
      "Specify settings file");

    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;

    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << desc << std::endl;
        ---->!!!!!!!! WHAT DO I DO HERE TO GET OUT !!!!!!!!<----
    }
    if (vm.count("settings")) {
        std::cout << "Settings file " << vm["settings"].as<std::string() << std::endl;
        return vm["settings"].as<std::string>();
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Settings file must be specified.");
    }
}
```

So my question is after I print the CLI 'help' message what do I do to exit my program?

1. Should my function not be returning std::string and just return an error code?
2. Should I throw an exception and catch it in main and then exit?
3. Is there a much nicer / better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've placed a responsibility where it doesn't belong.

Comment: So should I just put it back in main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another better way in my opinion, according to this post : [C++ catching all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315948/c-catching-all-exceptions)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

static bool checkHelp(char * const argv[])
{
    bool usage = (!strcmp(argv[1], "-h") or !strcmp(argv[1], "--help"));

    if (usage) {
        std::cout << "Print your usage" << std::endl;
    }
    return usage;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Set eval to default value */
    int eval = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    try {
        if (!checkHelp(argv)) {
            /*
            ** do some stuff here
            */
        }
    } catch (std::exception const &err) {
         /* update eval on throwed exceptions */
         eval = EXIT_FAILURE;
         std::cerr << "error: " << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return eval;
}
```

Doing by this way, you can manage all your program execution in error context and choose what to do : update return value, do other stuff, etc.
You don't break your main thread and prevent you from memory errors/leaks without exit by `exit()` function.

*1)* **eval** (for 'exit value') is instancianted and destroyed with **main context**. In accordance with the type of main's return value, we have to change it's value if an error occurred before returning it while exit the program.

*2)* In my example, I send argv to the checkHelp function who returned **true** if the first argument of my software (*argv[1]* here) is equal to **"-h"** or **"--help"**, if not *checkHelp* returns **false**. You can also do a loop on all argv arguments received by main.

*3)* Finally, `catch (std::exception const &err)` allows you to get your throwed exception by reference and print his message. So, you are using your main try/catch block in all his integrity.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my personal opinion: there isn't a best practice way but I prefer the first approach!

**1. Approach:**
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit

You can call the following function:

```
std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
```

**2. Approach:**
Create an exception.

```
throw "Please call me with some parameters!"
```

But I do not prefer this approach. For some users the exception looks like there is an internal software error...

Comment: Just a note that it is bad practice to throw values that are not subclasses of `std::exception`